# setState works only for first time in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

on clicking cross it changes to zero  because we setState but how this change
reflect to global arr that is why it do not reset for 2nd time . it was not resetting for the first time alse but to show effect i added arr2

so i thought maybe this is due to let arr so i changed it cosnt arr but still it does not work .
so i add a new arr2 const to test but it works for the first time only

```js
const cross = "http://clipart-library.com/data_images/49124.png"
const zero  = "http://clipart-library.com/data_images/367486.png"

const arr = [[cross,cross,cross],
             [cross,cross,cross],
             [cross,cross,cross]]

const arr2 = [[cross,cross,cross],
             [cross,cross,cross],
             [cross,cross,cross]]


class ResetButton extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.reset = this.reset.bind(this)
    }

reset(){
    
    this.props.reset()
}

render(){

    return <div>
           <h>Reset all img to cross  </h>
      <button onClick={this.reset}>{"RESET"} </button>
           </div>
}

}





class Box extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.changeImage = this.changeImage.bind(this)
    }

    changeImage(r,c){
      this.props.changeImage(r,c)
    }

    render(){
        let row     = this.props.row
        let column  = this.props.column
        return <img src = {this.props.src} height={25} width={25} onClick={()=>this.changeImage(row,column)} />
    }
}


class BoxColumn extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.changeImage = this.changeImage.bind(this)
    }

    changeImage(r,c){
        this.props.changeImage(r,c)
    }

    render(){
       let row = this.props.row
        return <div>
            {this.props.src.map((i,j)=><Box src={i} row={row} column={j}  changeImage={this.changeImage} key={j}/>) }
               </div>
    }
}
    

class BoxRow extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {src :arr}
        this.changeImage = this.changeImage.bind(this)
        this.reset  = this.reset.bind(this)
    }

    reset(){
        
        this.setState({src:arr2})
        
    }
    
    changeImage(r,c){
       //console.log(r,c)
        let srcArr = [...this.state.src]
        srcArr[r][c] = zero
        this.setState({src:srcArr})
    }

    render(){

        return <div>
             
          <p>Click on image to change cross image to zero</p>
            {this.state.src.map((i,j)=><BoxColumn src={i} row={j} changeImage={this.changeImage} key={j}/>) }
          <ResetButton reset={this.reset}/>
             </div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<BoxRow />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"> </div>
```

Comment: Your problem is a bit more unclear. Can you re-edit your question? can you add your errors?

Comment: i can change cross image to zero image by clicking on the img element and i want that whenever i select type from zero or cross then all the image should reinitialse to cross

Comment: actually i am in the middle of making tic tac toe game may be this help

Comment: `let srcArr = [...this.state.src]` will only make a copy of the outer array - you'll need to copy the inner array as well which you modify.

Comment: can you describe where do i need to copy inner arr

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion based on your example. I would encourage you to use this opportunity to refactor your components to functions and use the `useState` api. It's a lot more elegant than the class component state syntax and is becoming the more conventional approach.
Also, if you're going to use class components, you can avoid needing to bind your methods explicitly in the constructor by refactoring them to arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok with only **arr**. No need to introduce **arr2**. what was happened... when you change the value **arr** by clicking mouse it sets your changes to original **arr**, so after setting state, setState sets the **arr** that was changed already. What I do, before using setState, I reset every indices of **arr** with **cross**. Just replace `changeType` function with below one in BoxRow Component.

```
changeType(selectedType) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                arr[i][j] = cross;

        this.setState({src: arr, type: selectedType})
    }
```

Comment: yes it will work . another option is to create a local arr in changetype with default values but is this the only way .My real question is how changes made to setState reflects to global arr

Comment: Because, both objects (global and state) has same reference

Comment: event if i change `this.state = {src:arr}` to `this.state = {src:[...arr]}` still  problem exists